# ¿Leer cadena de varias lineas ingresada en consola de PYTHON?

Tags: python

Uso Python 3.6 e intento leer un dato de entrada de varias lineas para almacenarla en una variable y luego administrar cada linea en una lista por ejemplo. La estructura del codigo es algo sencillo como esto:

```
    print("Escriba la lista de ciudades de la siguiente forma:")
    print("Ciudad origen | Ciudad destino | Ruta | Distancia")
    cad.append(input())
```

Quiero ingresar 3 lineas por ejemplo (sin presionar ENTER, copiando y pegando por ejemplo)

> > Linea 1
> >     Linea 2
> >     Linea 3
> >     Y quiero que python almacene en una variable las 3 lineas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input` (python 3.x) retorna una cadena, para dividir cada elemento puedes usar el método [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) de las cadenas usando el separador adecuado, en tu caso `|`:

```
print("Escriba la lista de ciudades de la siguiente forma:")
print("Ciudad origen | Ciudad destino | Ruta | Distancia")
cadd = input().split('|')
```

**Edición:**
Vale, lo que deseas por lo que parece es una entrada multilinea, input solo lee hasta encontrarse con un final de linea ('\n', '\r', ...). Una forma sencilla sería usar un ciclo `while` infinito. Para detener la entrada se puede especificar cualquier cosa, en este caso introducir una linea en blanco indica que el usuario termina el ingreso de datos:

```
print("Escriba la lista de ciudades de la siguiente forma:")
print("Ciudad origen | Ciudad destino | Ruta | Distancia")

lista = []
while True:
    inputs = input()
    if inputs:
        lista.append(inputs)
    else:
        break
print(lista)
```

En este caso se puede copiar y pegar un texto con varias lineas en la consola y finalmente cada linea será un elemento de la lista.

Comment: No es eso, quiero ingresar 3 lineas por ejemplo
>>Linea 1 
Linea 2
Linea 3
Y quiero que python almacene en una variable las 3 lineas

Comment: @VictorPaternina he editado la pregunta a ver si es eso lo que necesitas, para que sea más fácil ayudarte intenta siempre redactar la pregunta lo más clara y concreta posible, indicando  que entrada y que salida esperas, problema concreto de tu código, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias, obtuve el resultado que deseaba.